# Iterating Through N Level Children

Tags: javascript, jquery, iteration

This seems like something neat that might be "built into" jQuery but I think it's still worth asking.

I have a problem where that can easily be solved by iterating through all the children of a element. I've recently discovered I need to account for the cases where I would need to do a level or two deeper than the "1 level" (just calling .children() once) I am currently doing.

```
jQuery.each(divToLookAt.children(), function(index, element)
    {
        //do stuff
    }
    );
```

This is what I'm current doing. To go a second layer deep, I run another loop after doing stuff code for each element.

```
jQuery.each(divToLookAt.children(), function(index, element)
{
     //do stuff
    jQuery.each(jQuery(element).children(), function(indexLevelTwo, elementLevelTwo)
    {
        //do stuff
    }
    );  
}
);
```

If I want to go yet another level deep, I have to do this all over again.

This is clearly not good. I'd love to declare a "level" variable and then have it all take care of. Anyone have any ideas for a clean efficient jQueryish solution?

Thanks!

Comment: What is it that you look for in the elemtns?

Comment: +1 because I'm surprised jquery doesn't have a native selector for this, and because I kinda miss manual dom traversal lol.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an awesome question because of the levels deep catch. [Check out the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7448b/1/).

Converted this to a plugin.

**Activate**

```
$('#div').goDeep(3, function(deep){ // $.fn.goDeep(levels, callback)
    // do stuff on `this`
});
```

**Plugin**

```
$.fn.goDeep = function(levels, func){
    var iterateChildren = function(current, levelsDeep){
        func.call(current, levelsDeep);

        if(levelsDeep > 0)
            $.each(current.children(), function(index, element){
                iterateChildren($(element), levelsDeep-1);
            });
    };

    return this.each(function(){
        iterateChildren($(this), levels);
    });
};
```

Comment: Make it just filter stuff out instead of being some limited capability visitor. More jquery'ish/flexible imo.

Comment: @chris - I cannot see how getting all elements withing a container, then filtering based on a dynamic selector could be more flexible/efficient

Answer (score 2):

This question is awesome :-)

If you know your DOM is not too gigantic, you could just find all the descendants and filter out the ones that don't qualify:

```
var $parent = $('#parent');
var $childrenWithinRange = $parent.find('*').filter(function() {
  return $(this).parents('#parent').length < yourMaxDepth;
});
```

After that, the jQuery instance "$childrenWithinRange" would be all the child nodes of that parent `<div>` that are within some maximum depth.  If you wanted exactly that depth, you'd switch "<" to "===".  I may be off by one somewhere.

Comment: +1 This is how I would do it, unless I felt I'd be filtering out way too much stuff do to very deep descendants.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just do it with the [`all-selector`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/all-selector/), the [`child-selector`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) and [`multiple-selector`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)    like this:

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/mDu9q/1/

```
$('#start > *,#start > * > *,#start > * > * > *').doSomething();
```

...or if you *only* wanted to target the children 3 levels deep, you could do this:

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/mDu9q/2/

```
$('#start > * > * > *').doSomething();
```

Both of these selectors are valid for `querySelectorAll`, which means big performance boost in supported browsers.

Answer (score 1):

The question sounds like the answer could be XPATH. I'm not well informed about the browser-support, but in XPATH you only need to create a path like

```
/*/*/*/*
```

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/introduction_to_using_xpath_in_javascript
  (works in FF,Chrome,Safari,Opera)
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa335968%28v=vs.71%29.aspx
  (didn't try it yet)

Answer (score 0):

```
var lvlFunc = function(elmt, depth) {
    if(depth > 0) {
        elmt.children().each(function(i, e){
            // do stuff on the way down
            lvlFunc($(this), --depth);
            // do stuff on the way out
        });
        // do stuff
    }
};

lvlFunc(divToLookAt, 3);
```

Make sure that you put your "do stuff" code in the right location if matters which order the "stuff" is performed in.